# Make an image "load" or "show" in a fade transition in Java

Tags: java, image, load, fade

I'm basically looking to make an image to be revealed as time passes, (i've got the settings for time etc) I'm just not sure how to set it to show the image pixel by pixel, growing in height. Aka, you start with no displayed image and then as time grows, it reveals more and more of the image, (going up) and finally reveals the image at the end.

It's like a transition in Java.

I've been messing around with it for ages, Googling everywhere for at least 3 hours. Can't get anywhere,

Here's my images as base:

```
BufferedImage img = null, img2 = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("9278.png"));
    img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("9279.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStacktrace();
}

g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, null);
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) Put `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch.  2) Use `this` instead of `null` for the image observer. 3) 'Fade' is wrong term for that effect.  I'm not sure what the official name is, but Dervall would be close with 'curtain effect'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want some sort of curtain effect, like when an image loads over a slow internet connection. I would approach it this way:

You want to use the `setClip` method of your `Graphics2D` object. Create a new `Rectangle` of the size you want the image to be drawn in, and pass that to `setClip` in graphics. This will cause the drawing of the image to be performed only inside the area specified by the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'll look it up, is there any docs you can link me to fast that would help me manoeuvrer setClip in my work?

Comment: Look to [`setClip(x,y,w,h)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setClip%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) or [`setClip(shape)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setClip%28java.awt.Shape%29).  As an aside, they are methods of the `Graphics` class, which are also available to (inherited by) the `Graphics2D` class.

Comment: God!

I didn't realise how easy that was! Now just to increase the height as the paint is drawn.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I spent hours on this only to find this such easy solution! Much love!

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy problem as you want somethings not directly integrated in swing, here's [the example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Fadeoutanimageimagegraduallygetmoretransparentuntilitiscompletelyinvisible.htm) I used to do the same,

you probably need to adapt it, but it's a good example of what you need

Comment: I've gone through all fading options, they're not the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: It worked, I just want it to fade as a curtain, not as a whole.

Comment: all right, I'm not a native english speaker I hadn't understand that.  Hope you'll find a way to do it